# trying to create a simple shell in c for win32 api

Tags: winapi

I went through the demo code given in the msdn documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx and i wanted to know if you knew how to get the `argv[]` command to execute in the `CreateProcess` function... when i try executing the file, it says create process failed when i try the following snippet and then i try to type in dir after i get the executable

```
 if( !CreateProcess( NULL,  
        argv[1],        
        NULL,           
        NULL,          
        FALSE,           
        0,              
        NULL,          
        NULL,           
        &pi )           
    )
```

Comment: In short,how do i pass the command line arguments like dir to my create process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dir is a command that cmd.exe executes; not a program you can execute with CreateProcess.  So to do what you want, you need to launch cmd.exe and pass "dir" on the command line to it.  The simplest way to do that is with the system function.  Your program should look something like this:

```
#include <process.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   system(argv[1]);
}
```

Obviously, you need to add error checking, but this should do what you want.

Here is a working example using CreateProcess.  Note that the /k flag tells cmd.exe to remain open after executing the command.  If you want it to execute the command and then exit, change /k to /c.

```
#include <windows.h>

void main()
{
   STARTUPINFO si;
   PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

   memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
   si.cb = sizeof(si);

   CreateProcess(NULL,  
                 "cmd.exe /k dir",
                 NULL,           
                 NULL,          
                 FALSE,           
                 CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,              
                 NULL, 
                 NULL,         
                 &si,           
                 &pi );           
}
```

Comment: when i run this program where do i enter "dir"? Also, i am supposed to execute these commands in a new process which is why i was using createprocess

Comment: You enter "dir" on your program's command line.  So if your program is named foo.exe, you would enter "foo dir".  The system function creates a new process, so you're good on that.

Comment: Thank you... will trying if( !CreateProcess( c:\...\cmd.exe,  
        argv[1],        
        NULL,           
        NULL,          
        FALSE,           
        0,              
        NULL,          
        NULL,           
        &pi ) work?

Comment: No, it will not work.  If you want to use CreateProcess, you need to form a single string composed of "cmd.exe" plus a space and then the command to execute.  For example:  "cmd.exe dir".  You then need to pass that as the second parameter to CreateProcess, not the first.

Comment: It still doesnot work when i pass cmd.exe as the second parameter.Is there anywhere i can read about simple shells in c for win32? i found a lot for linux but not windows

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a working example of CreateProcess.  And here is a good reference on cmd.exe.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MS-DOS_commands

Answer (score 0):

Just like the example in the link you posted, you require a pointer to a `STARTUPINFO` as the second last param, with any command line arguments being passed as the second param to `CreateProcess`. See the documentation on [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: oh..yeah.. i did that too... i used STARTUPINFO si and passed it as &si to the createprocess function... i dont know where to input the command line arg for the program to execute.

Comment: when i build and compile this program on the cl compiler, i get the object file and the .exe and i run the .exe but how do i ask the program to function as a shell and carry out "dir".

Comment: @maya: you pass the command line args to the app by running it through a bat file or the windows command line

Comment: bat file or through the windows command line, how? when i try it, i just get the error message saying createprocess failed.I am sorry but i am very new at this.