# Unable to execute a command as process

Tags: c, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [trying to create a simple shell in c for win32 api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273721/trying-to-create-a-simple-shell-in-c-for-win32-api)

I'm doing some C programming in Windows for a low level coding assignment and I'm trying    to get this create process to work however. I am try to trying to execute a command as a process, any command you can put into the dos prompt. I'm mainly trying execute "dir"
in a separate process. Can anyone see why this wouldn't work?

```
if (!CreateProcess(NULL, "dir",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        TRUE,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &si,
        &pi))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Create Process directly has Failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: When printing the error message, consider printing the actual error code as well (using the [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273721/trying-to-create-a-simple-shell-in-c-for-win32-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since dir is a cmd.exe built in you need to run cmd , ie set `lpApplicationName` to `cmd.exe` and  `lpCommandLine` to dir